# Operator on set of bounded sequences

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider the set of real bounded sequences $S_b:=\{(x_n)_n\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} | \sup_{n}|x_n|<\infty \}$ and an operator (i.e., infinite matrix) $A=(a_{ij})_{i,j\in\mathbb{N}}$ satisfying for fixed $i\in\mathbb{N}$ the condition that there is an $n_i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}} a_{ij}  = \sum_{k=1}^{n_i} a_{ij_k} = 0$, i.e., in every row are only finitely many non-zero elements and they sum to zero.
Is the set $S_b$ invariant under $A$, i.e., for $x\in S_b$ does it hold $Ax = \sum_{j\in\mathbb{N}}a_{ij}x_j \in S_b$? Yes or no answer is sufficient. But if you want to explain, do not hesitate.

And a source on that topic would be helpful because I haven't work with sequence spaces for quite some time.

Comment: Yes, thank you.
Adjusted assumptions that $A$ has only finitely many non-zero elements per row.

Answer (score 1):

We can have $a_{ij}=(-1)^j$ if $2^i<j\le 2^{i+1}$ and $=0$ otherwise. Then for $x_j=(-1)^j$, we obtain $(Ax)i=2^i$. In fact, we even get problems when $x_j=(-1)^n/n$ is a zero sequence instead of just bounded.